# jquery .css() returns object object?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, ajax, object

I have something like this:

```
    var windowH = $(window).height();
    var listH = $(".list").height();
    if(windowH > listH){
        $(".list").css({'height': windowH+'px'});   
        alert(windowH);
        alert($(".list").css({'height': windowH+'px'}));
    }
```

the second alert gives me `[object Object]` and therefore doesn't insert the correct css. can someone help?

Thanks

Comment: Why not just use `$('.list').height(windowH)`?

Comment: He only wants to resize if window height is > listHeight

Comment: @TobiasSpringer Blender is saying that instead of using `.css({})` method, inside of the if statement, why not just use the `.height()` method? Not a bad idea since each gets and sets using an integer...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`.css` method returns the jQuery object (For method chaining), so the alert result is nothing wrong.

Instead of using `.css`, try use `.height` method.

```
$(".list").height(windowH);
```

Comment: Ahh this does look cleaner. If I wanted to subtract some `px` like `50px` how would I do that in this situation? would it be more complicated?

Comment: @andrewliu `.height` returns an integer. You don't need to use `px`

Answer (score 3):

A call to `$(el).css(propertyName, value)` returns the element you're working with,.

This is so you can chain functions.

```
$(".list").css(propertyName, value).css(propertyName, value).remove(); // etc etc.
```

`windowH` is most likely a number, try `windowH.toString() + 'px'` if you want something like `"600px"`.

Comment: +1 For actually understanding that `.height()` returns an integer. But you wouldn't need `.toString() + 'px'` because using the `+` operator with a string will implicitly convert the integer to a string and append "px" because "px" is not an integer.

Comment: @ianpgall - Cheers for the `toString()` advice. Jumping between languages all days always leaves me a little skeptical, so I like to be explicit and keep on the safe side :)

Comment: Oh definitely, it's tough to remember what implicit things are done in what language, so no worries. You have to be careful with these kinds of things though. If you do `2 + 1 + 'px'`, you get "3px". If you do, `'px' + 2 + 1`, you get "px21". If you do `2 + 1 + 'px' + 2 + 1`, you get "3px21". Which makes sense - the operations are done from left to right, and as soon as a string is encountered, it uses concatenation, not addition.

Comment: Note that if you call `.css()` with one string parameter like `.css('height')` it will return the value, not a jQuery object. (And I'm pretty sure it's invalid to call `.css()` with no parameters as in your example.)

Comment: @nnnnnn - Yes, intended as an arbitrary example, but I have amended the post to be more accurate.

Answer (score 1):

Use this:

```
alert( $(".list").css('height') );
```

When you call the `.css()` method with a map of key/value pairs like in your code it assumes you are trying to *set* those CSS properties, and it returns the jQuery object you called it on (which `alert()` quite correctly displays as `"[object Object]"`). That's why you can chain other jQuery methods after `.css({...})`.

If you call `.css()` with just the name of a particular property like I've shown above then it returns the value of that property so that will work within an `alert()`. (Note though that if your jQuery object has more than one element, i.e., if `".list"` matches multiple elements, `.css('height')` returns the height value for the first element only.)

EDIT: Note that this behaviour in the `.css()` method is the same as for other jQuery methods that can be used both to set and get "something", like `.val()`, `.html()`, `.prop()`, etc. When called with parameters that *set* a value these methods all return a jQuery object, but when called with parameters that *get* a value they all return the appropriate value.

Comment: If you call `.css()` with any parameters, it knows you are trying to "set" (2 parameters - first is key, second is value). Empty parameters mean "get". Sometimes, but is usually the standard/pattern they use

Comment: @ianpgall - I don't think it's valid to call `.css()` with no parameters. If you pass one parameter that specifies the css property that you want to get the value of. (Other methods like `.val()` do a "get" when no parameter is passed.)

Comment: Crap, not what I meant. You're right, totally wrong with that example with `css`

Answer (score 0):

First, you have to set the property and then alert the appropriate values . ..

try

```
    var windowH = $(window).height();
var listH = $(".list").height();
if(windowH > listH){
    $(".list").css({'height': windowH+'px'});   
    alert(windowH);
    $(".list").css('height', windowH+'px');

    alert(listH);
}
```